# Why is the header row not showing a border on my HTML table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following CSS code for my HTML table, but for some reason the border doesn't go over the header row (the `<th>`). It's definitely something simple that I missing, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
#dependenciesTable tr.odd {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#dependenciesTable tr.even {
    background-color: #CDE0F6;
}

#dependenciesTable
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

I am using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to add these odd even striping.

```
$('#dependenciesTable tr:odd').addClass('odd');
$('#dependenciesTable tr:even').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Superstringcheese's answer:

Some browsers (IE, ahem) behave strangely when you try to style things based on `<tr>`s, since conceptually they're just elements to hold `<td>`s and `<th>`s. So, you want to change your CSS to this:

```
#dependenciesTable td.odd {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#dependenciesTable td.even {
    background-color: #CDE0F6;
}

#dependenciesTable 
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And your jQuery code to this:

```
$('#dependenciesTable tr:odd td').addClass('odd');
$('#dependenciesTable tr:even td').addClass('even');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add styling to TR, add it to TD. So:

```
tr.odd td {background:000;}
```